# Making a linked picture just a picture via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've inherited a sheet with a load of linked pictures in. I need to make various version of said sheet for different countries. Trouble is when I update the values in the sheet to create the output for Denmark it updates the linked pictures in the file VBA has saved off as Sweden.

Is there any way I can get VBA to unlink the linked pictures?

Comment: Try [Break a link to an external reference in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Break-a-link-to-an-external-reference-in-Excel-f1ca8b08-4f24-4af6-92e5-f4fdb1442748) or [Removing phantom external links in Excel](https://superuser.com/a/1146299)

Comment: Can you provide the code for Denmark and Sweden please.